# SQL Server stored procedure validity checking

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I check the validity of a stored procedure programmatically? Meaning that if no errors are found it will execute. How can I detect things like invalid tables names in "from" or "join" clauses?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: SQL 2008 R2...I solved the problem using a SQL cursor,  I would post it, but I don't see where I can.

Comment: the basic solution reads sysobjects where type = 'P', then... set FMTONLY ON, try to execute the proc...EXEC @SPName WITH RESULT SETS NONE; then check for errors (see @@Error)...sorry for such a terse response.

Comment: That will only work for procedures that have no parameters (or have parameters with defaults). It will break for required parameters unless your cursor also iterates through (a) all combinations of parameters and (b) all behavior-affecting combinations of parameter *values*. As well as several other limitations noted in the answers below. Also please use `sys.procedures`, not the deprecated `sysobjects`.

Comment: all the stored procs have params...seems to work fine, what I'm i missing?

Comment: If you have a procedure with a *required* parameter, and you just say `EXEC @SPName;`, it should return an error, regardless of whether you're using `FMTONLY`, `WITH RESULT SETS NONE`, etc. Unless you just wrap everything in `TRY/CATCH` and ignore all errors, in which case I don't think your testing is proving what you think it's proving.

Comment: That's true...you will get error 201, expects parameter..., but you'll also get other errors, like 208 stating that there is an invalid object, for example:                                       Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DELETEForm, Line 13
Invalid object name 'Form'.  so filter out the 201s and any sp left with an error has a problem.

Comment: But you're making a naïve assumption that none of these stored procedures have control of flow logic or dynamic SQL that will only reach references to missing tables if *specific* parameters are used or when certain conditions are true (time of day, presence of certain data in a certain state, etc).

Comment: Ok...Thanks, I guess that's why it works, no flow control in any of the procs, they are all simple INSERTs, UPDATEs or DELETEs.

Comment: At least in this simple case

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how strictly you are defining "programmatically". If you mean a process that knows nothing of the proc it is evaluating, then you aren't going to get very far. In addition to the obstacles mentioned by @Aaron in his answer (i.e. Linked Servers, Dynamic SQL, OPENQUERY / OPENROWSET, deferred name resolution, etc), you also have the issue of permissions. The table names being correct doesn't help if the user cannot access them :).

An even bigger issue is the conditional execution of blocks of code. Consider the following test:

First we run it such that the conditional block is skipped.

```sql
DECLARE @RandomCondition INT,
        @Test INT;

SET @RandomCondition = 1;

IF (@RandomCondition = 2)
BEGIN
    SET @Test = 'a';
END;
SELECT @RandomCondition AS [RandomCondition];
GO
```

This encounters no errors and returns a result set of 1 row.

Second time around we run it such that the conditional block is entered.

```sql
DECLARE @RandomCondition INT,
        @Test INT;

SET @RandomCondition = 2;

IF (@RandomCondition = 2)
BEGIN
    SET @Test = 'a';
END;
SELECT @RandomCondition AS [RandomCondition];
GO
```

This encounters the following error (as expected):

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.

So you really can't even loop through a list of procs and run them by passing `NULL` in for all input params as different values for a particular parameter might cause it to take several different, and non-overlapping, paths.

On the other hand, if you are defining "programmatically" to mean "an automated process", then there is hope.

You really need to set up integration testing where you can set up the environment (if need be), execute it with specific parameter values, and test the output and/or any expected changes to the environment. AND you can set up as many tests for the same stored procedure as is required by the nature of each stored procedure.

The tool I prefer to use for such testing is [DbFit](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/). It has been a few years since I have used it, but it was soooo easy to use. Unlike some of the other SQL testing frameworks, it is completely unobtrusive, requiring no changes to your database(s). The tests are defined in a wiki so it is easy to create and update them. You can group tests together and even use variables across several pages (such as connection string info, etc). You can also automate it via command-line.

Even if you don't use DbFit, you should still have some testing framework as anything you can test for programmatically (in a strict sense) isn't worth the time it will take to set it up; it will catch such a small percentage of problems that you will still need something else to catch the other 80% - 90%.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest programmatic way would be just to try and execute them (using `TRY`/`CATCH`) and determining the class of error that results. Of course you'd only catch the first error, and this assumes that there isn't error handling in any of those procedures for missing objects.

Plus, as [@srutzky points out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89878/1186), there is more to calling stored procedures than just calling them - there is a set of test cases that increases exponentially with the number of parameters and the range of values each of those parameters can have - any combination could potentially make the procedure behave uniquely and encounter errors or logic problems that wouldn't be evident in any other case.

If you're *just* looking for invalid table names in databases on the local instance specifically, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT s.name, p.name, db = COALESCE(d.referenced_database_name, DB_NAME()),
  [schema] = d.referenced_schema_name, [object] = d.referenced_entity_name
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p
  ON s.[schema_id] = p.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
  ON p.[object_id] = d.referencing_id
  WHERE d.referenced_id IS NULL
    AND d.referenced_server_name IS NULL
    AND d.referenced_class = 1
    AND OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(COALESCE(d.referenced_database_name, DB_NAME()))
          + '.' + QUOTENAME(d.referenced_schema_name)
          + '.' + QUOTENAME(d.referenced_entity_name)) IS NULL;
```

Note that this specifically filters out 4-part references, because you can't really validate whether a 4-part name exists on another server without actually trying to access it (or working out some elaborate metadata queries against the linked server, which may not even be a SQL Server). So the solution focuses on objects that are referenced within the same instance.

Also note that this will miss anything that is constructed via dynamic SQL or using `OPENQUERY` / `OPENROWSET`, and probably some other loopholes too (like deferred name resolution issues that were corrected and later messed up again, or columns that were valid when the object was created but have since been dropped - I'm not sure how accurate this DMV is depending on which object in the chain has changed).